# NSImageView on NSVisualEffectView

Tags: nsmenuitem, nsvisualeffectview

I need to make NSMenuItem with icon at the right side. I ended up with custom view which contains NSTextField and NSImageView on top of NSVisualEffectView with selection material, that I use to imitate system selection. NSVisualEffectView is hidden by default.
But when the item is selected, my NSVisualEffectView appears on screen and image is drawn with background. How can I get rid of it? wantsLayer = YES and backgroundColor = CGColor.clear did not help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to add NSVisualEffectView explicitly. By default, menu items have NSVisualEffectView as superView. You can use that VisualEffectView to imitate the selection behavior. [Click here](https://github.com/kaush012/CustomMenuItem.git) to download a demo project.

Set image's `isTemplate` property to true. It will change according to appearance of menu item.