# OS X Menu Backgroung Color

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is there any way to determine it?
I have custom popups, so I'd want background color for menus would match real OS X independently on selected theme. 
None of current available are suitable. I looked for NSColor controlBackgroundColor, windowBackgroundColor and similar. all do not match.

Comment: NSView adopts a protocol named NSAppearanceCustomization, with a property named `effectiveAppearance` which returns an `NSAppearance` object. That might get you started.

Comment: This might solve your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748004/nsimageview-on-nsvisualeffectview/43391328#43391328  @dev_null

Comment: Thanks, the link helped, it pointed me to NSVisualEffectView  and company arround